# OOP PHP Database results to Array

Tags: php, oop

I am new to the idea of oop php and i am trying to write an irc php.

What I'm trying to do:
I am trying to query my database, get results from my database and put it into an array inside my program.

I tried making a new function to carry out the task and called it in the __construct function.

I have shortened the code but it pretty much looks like this:

Any thoughts and ideas are much appreciated.

```
class IRCBot
{    

    public $array = array();
    public $servername = "localhost";
    public $username = "root";
    public $password = "usbw";
    public $dbname = "bot";


function __construct()
{
    //create new instance of mysql connection
    $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname); 

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
    echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

    $this->database_fetch();

}

function database_fetch()
{
    $query = "SELECT word FROM timeoutwords";
    $result = mysqli_query($query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $array[] = $row();
        }
}

function main()
{
    print_r($array);
}



}

$bot = new IRCBot();
```

Comment: pass `$conn` into `$this->database_fetch();` as `$this->database_fetch($conn);` because `mysqli_query` need ist param as a link identifier but this will not work

Comment: make it property `$conn` as `$this->conn` than get this property into `main` method and call `database_fetch()` inside the `main()` method not in constructor

Comment: this will `if ($mysqli->connect_errno)` also not work

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Thanks for adding code examples to your question. Could you also add what the output is you're getting vs. what you're expecting? (Ie, errors, wrong output, etc.) That will help people see what exactly is going wrong and therefore help them help you.

Comment: 3 words: "check for errors".

Comment: @Fred-ii-: ahan one more comment for error_reporting :)

Comment: Amazing what *"three little words"* will do to someone's day, *eh?* @devpro

Comment: So @Reece, Have you implemented the answer given below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Changes***

**1)** Change `if ($mysqli->connect_errno)` to `if ($conn->connect_errno)`

**2)** Change `$array[] = $row();` to `$array[] = $row;`

**3)** Add `return $array;` in function `database_fetch()`

**4)** Call `database_fetch()` function inside `main()` function instead of constructor.

**5)** Add `$this->conn` in `mysqli_query()` (Thanks @devpro for pointing out.)

***Updated Code***

```
<?php
class IRCBot
{    

    public $array = array();
    public $servername = "localhost";
    public $username = "root";
    public $password = "usbw";
    public $dbname = "bot";
    public $conn;


    function __construct()
    {
        //create new instance of mysql connection
        $this->conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname); 

        if ($this->conn->connect_errno) 
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $this->conn->connect_errno . ") " . $this->conn->connect_error;
        }

    }

    function database_fetch()
    {
        $query = "SELECT word FROM timeoutwords";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $array[] = $row;
        }
        return $array;
    }

    function main()
    {
        $data = $this->database_fetch();
        print_r($data);
    }

}
```

***Quick Start***

- [Object Oriented Programming in PHP](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_object_oriented.htm)
- [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)
- [Principles Of Object Oriented Programming in PHP](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3909681)

Comment: friend, u missed the very important `mysqli_query($query)` ist param

Comment: now looks fine friend, just one suggestion u must need to initialize array `$array = array();`

Comment: I think, no need as in top `public $array = array();` is initialised @devpro

Answer (score 3):

**First of all you need to fix error from your constructor, you can modify as:**

```
function __construct()
{
    //create new instance of mysql connection
    $this->conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname); 

    if ($this->conn->connect_errno) 
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $this->conn->connect_errno . ") " . $this->conn->connect_error;
    }
    echo $this->conn->host_info . "\n";
}
```

- Here, you need to replace `$mysqli` with `$conn` because your link identifier is `$conn` not `$mysqli`
- No need to call `database_fetch()` here.
- You need to use `$conn` as a property.

**Now you need to modify `database_fetch()` method as:**

```
function database_fetch()
{
    $query = "SELECT word FROM timeoutwords";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
    $array = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $array[] = $row;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

- Here, you need to pass add first param in `mysqli_query()` which should be link identifier / database connection.
- Second, you need to use return for getting result from this function.

**In last, you need to modify your `main()` method as:**

```
function main()
{
    $data = $this->database_fetch();
    print_r($data);
}
```

- Here, you need to call `database_fetch()` method here and than print the data where you need.

Comment: I think `$array[] = $row();` will have problem here?

Comment: @NanaPartykar: :) opps

Comment: Sometimes happen. But, that was super for me `$_POST('pedert')`.

Comment: @NanaPartykar: hahaha, actually something like **shoro shoro k din** Early days

Comment: Ha Ha `:D` *Shuru Shuru Ke Din, Wo Bhi Kya Din They..* Let's Jump To Other Question Too. @devpro